# What is the easiest way to get certain values from string if the length changes?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have code that returns information about the user agent. I want to find the part that says `MSIE 10.0` and if it does then write `Internet Explorer 10.0` to the log file. Is there a way to do this without regular expressions? I'll use them if necessary, also I don't know if this string will always be same length so I don't think substring would be consistent.

> Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1;
>   Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

This is the code that returns the string:

```
var js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
const string script = "return navigator.userAgent"; // get the user agent
if (js != null)
{
    var userAgent = (string) js.ExecuteScript(script);
    Logger.Log(Loglevel.Debug, "Brower: {0}", userAgent);
}
```

Comment: User agent parsing is a pain, since the usage is not exactly standard. It looks like there's a library that has already done the work for you: http://user-agent-string.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides the [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that will return true if the particular string that you are searching for is present within the string that is calling Contains.

If you want to avoid hard-coding the version of the browser in your log statement, you can still use [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the value ... the following code would log: "Browser: Internet Explorer 10.0", assuming the value of userAgent is

"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)"

```
        if (userAgent.Contains("MSIE"))
        {
            int index = userAgent.IndexOf("MSIE") + 5; // + length of("MSIE ")
            int length = userAgent.IndexOf(';', index) - index;
            Logger.Log(Loglevel.Debug, "Browser: Internet Explorer {0}",
                userAgent.Substring(index, length)); 
        }
```

The first IndexOf will retrieve the index of userAgent past the space after "MSIE".  The second IndexOf uses that index as a starting point to find the next semicolon; the length of the difference of those two indices.  At that point, the Substring call will return the version number associated with MSIE in the userAgent string.

Comment: The output is "Browser: Internet Explorer 10.0"...thanks...I was wondering how to use the semicolons as anchors, that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if specified string contains another string:

```
if (userAgent.Contains("MSIE 10.0")){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a string.Contains() call on the user agent string.

```
bool contains = userAgent.Contains("MSIE 10.0");
if(contains)
{
  //whatever
}
```

Simple, no regex. I use it in some different projects, works ok. But beware false positives if the string you are looking for changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(userAgent.Contains("MSIE 10.0"))
      File.AppendAllText("Logfilepath","InternetExplorer 10.0");
```